# LARAVEL 5 sending image to controller using AJAX

Tags: ajax, image, file, laravel

I have some issues when I want to pass an image to controller through Ajax. any help?  This is my code

//ROUTE

```
Route::post('get-image', 'CreateImageController@get_image');
```

//IMAGE.BLADE.PHP

```
{!! Form::open([ 'id'=>'upload-doc','files'=>true ]) !!}

{!! Form::file('fileupload', ['id'=>'fileupload', 'onchange'=>"this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" ], null) !!}Browse
<button type="button" id="uploadFile">Upload</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

//AJAX

```
action  = "<?php echo action('CreateImageController@get_image'); ?>";
$.ajax({
    url:    action,
    type:   'POST',
    data:   new FormData($("#upload_doc")[0]),
    cache:  false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.display);
    }
});
```

// CONTROLLER function get_image()

```
public function get_image(){

        $name = '';
        $image = \Input::file('fileupload');
        $validator = \Validator::make([$image], ['image' => 'required']);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $name = "FAIL";
        }
        else{
            $name = "SUCCESS";
        }

        $data = array('display' => $name);
        echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

The result I get everytime is "FAIL". what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Since  I was only getting the file when I submit the form. I decided to add

```
$("#upload-doc").submit();  
var formData = new FormData($('#upload-doc')[0]);
```

inside my jquery method

```
$("#uploadFile").click(function(e) {

$("#upload-doc").submit();
var formData = new FormData($('#upload-doc')[0]);
action="<?php echo action('CreateImageController@get_image'); ?>";

$.ajax({
    url:    action,
    type:   'POST',
    data:   formData,
    cache:  false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function(data){
        alert('in success');
        console.log(data);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
if (Input::file('fileupload')) {

}
```

as a way of validation.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply; I tried that and `  if (\Input::hasFile('fileupload')) ` , but no luck. I am wondering if the controller actually receives the file.

Comment: make sure you have this in your controller use section  `use Input;
` and remove the \ for the Input:: ....

Comment: I just did that. It is still giving me the same results.

Comment: post the source of the view after your render it so view the page in yoru browse, copy whats in between the body tags and past it here or use pastitbin or something.

Comment: I don't get how it goes through when I submit the form using a submit button, but not when I use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

@SAri Yono, there's no view after I pass it; it is sent back to the ajax jquery to display the result with an alert/console.log

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  

$("#upload-doc").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$.ajaxSetup({
 headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')    }
}); 

$.ajax({
   url:     action,
   type:    'POST',
   data:    new FormData($("#upload_doc")[0]),
   cache:   false,
   dataType: 'json',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false, 
   success: function(data){
        console.log(display);
   }
});

e.preventDefault();

});
</script>
```

Between body tags I only have the Form.

```
{!! Form::open([ 'id'=>'upload-doc','files'=>true ]) !!}
{!! Form::file('fileupload', ['id'=>'fileupload'], null) !!}
<button type="button" id="uploadFile">Upload</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The Console.log displays this `Object {display: "FAIL"}`

Comment: why dont you return Input::all(); just so we can see what is getting passed over